# Gitlab CE password synchronized with Active Directory

Tags: gitlab, cas, gitlab-omnibus

I've configured Gitlab CE 9.1.2 with OmniAuth and a CAS server (Single sign on) that authenticates against an Active Directory. The login process is working fine with the `auto_create` option to make the automatic signup, etc... but when the user is logged in is asked for set a password in order to use the `https` protocol to use the git repositories.

Is there any property or configuration to **synchronize the Gitlab password with the Active Directory** to avoid this extra step for the user?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Here is the solution: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/32199